# Python socket connection not working properly

Tags: python, sockets, tcp

Included below is the code that I am currently using:

```
soc1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
ADDR = (HOST,PORT)
soc1.connect(ADDR)
soc1.send('WILL SEND')
```

The error message that I receive when running the above code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\workspace\wx_python_test\chat_server.py", line 25, in <module>
    soc1.connect(ADDR)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10061]
```

Could anyone please explain what the issue is that I am experiencing and how I can correct it?

Full source code: http://pastie.org/4245314

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.error: [Errno 10061]`  indicates that the port you are trying to connect to is not open.  You need to make sure that the port is open and something is listening for your connection to be made.

It appears that you are trying to test a chat server.  In order for the chat server to work properly you will want to make sure that it is currently listening on the specified port.

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/examples/) provides a good framework if you haven't checked it out previously.

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.protocols.basic import LineReceiver
from twisted.internet import reactor

class Chat(LineReceiver):

    def __init__(self, users):
        self.users = users
        self.name = None
        self.state = "GETNAME"

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.sendLine("What's your name?")

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        if self.users.has_key(self.name):
            del self.users[self.name]

    def lineReceived(self, line):
        if self.state == "GETNAME":
            self.handle_GETNAME(line)
        else:
            self.handle_CHAT(line)

    def handle_GETNAME(self, name):
        if self.users.has_key(name):
            self.sendLine("Name taken, please choose another.")
            return
        self.sendLine("Welcome, %s!" % (name,))
        self.name = name
        self.users[name] = self
        self.state = "CHAT"

    def handle_CHAT(self, message):
        message = "<%s> %s" % (self.name, message)
        for name, protocol in self.users.iteritems():
            if ':' in message:
                self.exc(message.split(':')[0])
            if protocol != self:
                protocol.sendLine(message)

    def exc(self, cmd):
        print cmd
        if cmd == 'who':
            for i in self.users:
                print i


class ChatFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self):
        self.users = {} # maps user names to Chat instances

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        return Chat(self.users)


reactor.listenTCP(8123, ChatFactory())
reactor.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your python is fine - check your network config and that you can actually connect to the specified host/port. You are getting Windows socket error 10061 - this is defined below:.

> WSAECONNREFUSED 10061 Connection refused. No connection could be made
>   because the target computer actively refused it. This usually results
>   from trying to connect to a service that is inactive on the foreign
>   host—that is, one with no server application running.

Try doing `telnet host port` from your terminal window - and see if you can connect. If not, resolve the network issue first.